# Merge data from a csv file into Oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle, csv, fgetcsv

I have a php script that inserts data from a csv file into an Oracle table :

```
$handle = fopen('file.txt', "r");
for($i =1;($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE; $i++) {
// The query uses placeholders for data
$sql = "INSERT INTO table
                (col1,col2,col3,col4)
            VALUES
                (:val1,:val2,:val3,:val4)";
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql);

// The data is bound to the placeholders
$sth->bindParam(':val1', $data[0]);
$sth->bindParam(':val2', $data[1]);
$sth->bindParam(':val3', $data[2]);
$sth->bindParam(':val4', $data[3]);

// The row is actually inserted here
$sth->execute();
$sth->closeCursor();
```

Now i'm trying  to replace the insert with a **merge** so I can do an isert only if the data does not exist already.

I took a look at some SO questions and the Oracle documentation, but still can't figure that out (without using procedures, whice is all i found...)

can you please help ?

Comment: *Now i'm trying to replace the insert with a merge so I can do an isert only if the data does not exist already.* Why? What's the problem with the plain `INSERT`? If you have required constraints defined on the table, then you would not have to think about the existing rows.

Comment: You're right. i can use a plain **INSERT**. but I will need the **MERGE** query to do some advanced stuff (using the when matched and when not matched)..Can you help me with the syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, if you only want to do an `INSERT` then you don't need to use `MERGE`. If you have proper **constraints** defined on the **table**, then you don't have to worry about **validating** the **existing rows** in the table.

Anyway, as per your comments to the question, you want to use **MERGE**. So, here are few examples of the [optional] **MATCHED** and **NOT MATCHED** clauses valid for releases 10g and up:

**Both clauses present**

```
MERGE INTO test1 a
  USING (SELECT :val1,:val2,:val3,:val4 FROM DUAL) b
    ON (a.key = b.key) -- put the required join key
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET a.col = b.col
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (col1,col2,col3,col4)
    VALUES (b.object_id, b.status);
```

**No matched clause, insert only**

```
MERGE INTO test1 a
  USING (SELECT :val1,:val2,:val3,:val4 FROM DUAL) b
    ON (a.key = b.key) -- put the required join key
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (col1,col2,col3,col4)
    VALUES (b.object_id, b.status);
```

**No not-matched clause, update only**

```
MERGE INTO test1 a
  USING (SELECT :val1,:val2,:val3,:val4 FROM DUAL) b
    ON (a.key = b.key) -- put the required join key
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET a.col = b.col;
```

See some usage examples [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g.php).